# Full width flexSlider with centered direction arrows

Tags: fullscreen, flexslider

I am using flexSlider in a full width mode
for a site that I'm building.see here:
http://clients.tipoos.com/glam/
notice that the site hasthis full width section for the slider but all other content
is centered using a consistent class called: **.main**

What I'm trying to accomplish seems pretty easy but I can't make it work:
I would like to keep the slider full width but center the arrows like so:

[image]

I tried writing small Jquery to wrap the arrows with div but it didn't work.
neither **wrap** nor **wrapAll** was working..

will appreciate any help
Thanks

Comment: What about giving `margin-right` and `margin-left` to the arrows.

Comment: that's not a good idea because the site is responsive all the way and you will have to change the values to all viewports. the direction needs to be wrapping the arrows UL element with Wrap function in Jquery

Comment: You don't have to change values just put `margin-right: 20%` for right arrow and `margin-left: 20%` for left arrow.

Comment: It works, however it isn't a good idea because this site is responsive and I will have to adjust the margins for each viewport..  anyway to accomplish wrapping the navigation with a wrapper which will keep them centered at all time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. hope it will help anyone here.
in order to center the arrows but still having a full width slider
I used the follwing CSS:

```
.flexslider .flex-direction-nav {
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  max-width: 980px;
  position: relative;

}
```

Explanation:

**margin: 0 auto !important;**
this centers the arrows container

**max-width: 980px;**
giving a fixed width to depending on your website width

**position: relative;**
this makes the magic. it allows the arrows to be positioned inside the main div

I also added negative top position to my arrows but that's only in my case
hope that helps anyone.